# Prove that a preorder is not anti symmetric

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $\prec$ be a relation on the set $ A = Z \times (N  \setminus \{0\}) $ in this way:

A. $<a,b> \prec <c,d> $ if $ ad \le bc$

Prove that $\prec$ is a Preorder and show it's not anti-symmetric.

B. Let $E$ be a relation on the set $A$: $xEy$ if $x \prec y$ and $y \prec x$ prove that E is an equivalence relation

I started with showing that $\prec$ is reflexive and transitive like this:

Let $<x,y> \in A$
Need to show that: 
$$xy \le xy$$
Indeed.
Transitive: 
Let $<a,b> \prec <c,d>$  and  $<c,d> \prec <e,f>$
Show that $<a,b> \prec <e,f>$

If $ad \le bc $ and $cf \le de$
$$adcf \le bcde$$
$$(cd)af \le (cd)be $$
If $ cd \ne 0$
$$af \le be$$
And that's why it's transitive.

Should I deal with that case $cd = 0$? how can I check it for this value?
I couldn't show it's not anti symmetric either and would like some help with B.

Thanks :)!
$$$$

Comment: Write down the definition of "antisymmetric" -- how much do you need to know about a relation in order to demonstrate that it _doesn't_ have that property?

Comment: that for ever $ ad \prec bc$  and $ bc \prec ad$ exist $ ad \ne bd $ but it is indeed equal isn't is?

Comment: x @user: That doesn't seem to be the definition of "antisymmetric". You need to start by being clear about what "antisymmetric" means. _Afterwards_ you can attempt to specialize that definition to the relation in question, but _first_ you need to understand _in general_ what it is you need to know about a relation in order to be able to say it is not antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

A relation $R$ on a set $S$ is antisymmetric if for all $x,y \in S$,

$$xRy\,\,\text{ and }\,\, yRx \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = y$$

To show your relation is *not* antisymmetric, all you need is one counterexample.

---

$S$ is this case is the set $\mathbb{Z} \times \left(\mathbb{N} - \{0\}\right)$, and $R$ is defined by $$<a,b>R<c,d> \qquad \iff \qquad ad \leq bc$$

If we want a counterexample, we need $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad\leq bc$ and $cb \leq da$ but $<a,b> \neq <c,d>$.

A counterexample is $$a=2 \qquad\qquad b=1 \qquad \qquad c=6 \qquad \qquad d=3$$

Why is this a counterexample?